# Is working for Facebook & Google haram and even take online courses for certificationfrom such companies offering for future job?

Tags: halal-haram

I'm really confused and I need a clear answer. I'm in a doubt whether I should take this Google's project management course and it's certification for future job offers or not? And is it haram to work for Google & Facebook since most of their revenue comes from advertisement?? And isn't most of their advertisement including bad stuff??? What should I do? Should I not go for the course Google is offering? And is working with such companies haram? Please explain clearly with evidence from the Shari'ah

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its haram to work at FB or Google or studying Courses from there

---

### 1.About Taking Courses

All You are doing is just taking ilm(Knowledge) from them, for e.g. many our Muslim students study in countries like Germany, UK, USA etc. by non Muslim teachers in numerous different field like Engineering, Medical, etc. So does that mean they all are doing haram?. The answer is NO! they aren't, so its an example that we sees everyday.

Imam Ali ibn Abu Talib, 4th Caliph (may Allah be pleased with him), once said, "I would be slave of a person who teaches me a letter"
So we can see that how much knowledge is important in Islam and from Imam Ali karamallahwajahul kareem's blessed statement we can see that it is not important who  teaches you ilm, its more important that you should acquire ilm as much as you can.

### 2.About Working For them

From Various Islamic Sources we can see that many Sahaba Ikram worked for the non Muslims. E.g. Imam Ali karamallahwajahul kareem worked for a jewish men in his Date farm So its not haram to work under a non Muslims and about bad things in FB/google ads its not something you should worry cause they are doing the bad thing not you so its not haram to work for them as long as you are not doing the same thing.